# Efficient query to lookup stuff in a word index

Tags: sql, indexing, full-text-search

I have two tables defined like this:

```
Page(id), Index(page_id, word)
```

page_id in Index is a foreign key to Page so that each Page is
connected to a group of Index entries. The Index table is a index for
the Page table so that you can do fast text searching. E.g:

```
SELECT page_id FROM Index where word = 'hello'
```

Would select all page_id's for all pages containing the word
'hello'. But now I want to select all page_id's for pages that contain
all of the words 'word1', 'word2' and 'word3'. The best query I can
come up with for this is:

```
SELECT page_id
FROM Index
WHERE word IN ('word1', 'word2', 'word3')
GROUP BY page_id
HAVING COUNT(1) = 3;
```

It works, but I wonder if someone can think of an alternative more
efficient query?

[edit] The above example is slightly simplified. In the real Index table word is replaced with a word_id column that references a Word table. But the basic approach is the same. The RDBMS is PostgreSQL and there is about 2m rows in the Index table and 20k rows in Page.

Answer (score 0):

As a small thing, I wouldn't call a table `Index`, that's bound to be confusing :)

Your query would find pages with 3 index entries for `word1`.  That might not be a problem, but you could change the `having` to:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT word) = 3
```

to avoid this problem.

How this query performs compared to other depends on a lot of factors, like keyword density, the DBMS you use, and the total amount of rows.  I would not worry about it until you encountered an actual performance problem.